# while loop condition for fibonacci output

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm trying to figure out how I can set a conditional statement in the while loop that will take the users input of a desired fibonacci number and calculate the corresponding fib number. User inputs 8 and program outputs 34. Any hint that can point me in the right direction or help me see the problem from a different angle would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    bool exit;
    int fib;
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 2;
    int fib3 = 0;

    cout << "The first Fibonacci number is 1" << endl;
    cout << "The second Fibonacci number is 2" << endl;
    cout << "what other Fibonacci number would you like? Enter -888 to exit: ";
    cin >> fib;

    while(fib ) //condition that makes sure output is the fibonacci the user is looking for
    {
        fib3 = (fib1+fib2);
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = fib3;

        cout << "...and the Fibonnaci is..... " << fib << endl;
    }
    if(fib == -888)
    {
        exit = true;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile and run the program? How does it behave when you input `1`? And for `-888`? Did the compiler give you any warnings?

Comment: I did compile, when I input 1 it runs infinitely. I haven't been able to come up with a condition that works. for -888 there is a warning that the code will never execute, I had it more as a placeholder for how I could have the user exit the loop after they were done asking for fib numbers.

Comment: Do as @P0W or @ChantryCargill wrote: decrement your `fib` index so that you know you are to stop when the index becomes zero. But test it for `-888` (or any negative value) before the loop, so you will not fall into repeating decrementing a negative value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible answers.

One is to calculate the Fibonacci number using the closed form solution, which is \frac{(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^n - (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^n}{\sqrt{5}}.

Another is to use a loop structure, which is how you are doing it. I do not want to answer the question for you, but you need a counter variable in your loop structure. Start it at 1 and count up until you reach the desired iteration of the fibonacci number.

Something like

```
i = 1;
while(i < n)
{
    i++;
    //code
}
```

Comment: You can go for counter.

Comment: The closed form solution doesn't really work with floating point arithmetic.